# Identify a row that follow two conditions

Tags: r

I need to identify which row follow the two following conditions:
- The row before present monthly rainfall lower than 20
- The row after present monthly rainfall higher than 20

I'm trying to identify when planting season starts, for that I wanted to say (for example): The planting season will start in the month when the month before the precipitation was lower than 20 but the month after is higher. In this example I sent you that month will be October because in September the rainfall is equal to 2 but in November equal to 100. I need to write a function that gives me the index corresponding to that month.

```r
df <- data.frame(month=c(1:12),monthly_rainfall=c(60,67,164,65,5,3,0,1,2,24,100,102))
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `lead()` and `lag()` functions along with `filter()`

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  filter(lag(monthly_rainfall) < 20,
         lead(monthly_rainfall) > 20)

  month monthly_rainfall
1     9                2
2    10               24
```

You can get the index with

```r
df %>% mutate(planting_season = lag(monthly_rainfall) < 20 & lead(monthly_rainfall) > 20) %$% 
       planting_season %>% 
       which()

[1]  9 10
```

Or you could get the month with:

```r
df %>% filter(lag(monthly_rainfall) < 20,
              lead(monthly_rainfall) > 20) %$% 
              month

[1]  9 10
```

Comment: That’s good to hear. If it solved your problem please accept the answer so that others may find it.

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```r
get_months <- function(x, high = 20, low = 20) {
    n <- length(x)
    which(c(NA, x[1:(n-1)]) < high & c(x[2:n], NA) > low)
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```r
get_months(df$monthly_rainfall)
# 9 10
```

Comment: you could also parameterize it with `y` and `z` arguments so that if the OP wants to change the previous and next months lower and upper bounds, i.e. `which(c(NA, x[1:(n-1)]) < y & c(x[2:n], NA) > z)`